# I want to bind gridview of all D:\ drive file folders in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to bind gridview of all D:\ drive file folders in asp.net? and download the file?
how is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basic need 2 functions to travel to the directories and files...

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(CurrentFolderPath, "*");
System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(CurrentFolderPath, "*");
```

and then use a generic handler (.ashx) to render the results (and download this file).